# Does a non-persistent SATA drive exist?

Tags: memory, data-storage, sata

Is there a non-persistent SATA drive, like made of RAM chips or similar?

AFAIK there are/were PCI cards only with RAM chips. What about SATA devices?

I am *not* looking for a (persistent) SSD.

Comment: What's your use-case for which a regular RAM Disk is not sufficient? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: My Server is filled wirh RAM and all modules at maximum. To add more I need to upgrade the entire system. Use case: lot of reads and writes of temporary data, but more than the ram in the server. A typical ssd will writeout in a short time. So I am looking for other solutions cheaper than replacing the whole server.

Comment: Does it really matter, in that case, that the data is volatile? It's only going to clear at reboot, which I assume is not going to be frequent on a server. Just run it to a regular [large] SSD & overwrite/TRIM as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very very small niche market for physical devices that use DRAM for storage because software solutions like [ImDisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/) and [RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) can do basically everything that those devices can with no extra hardware at all. (And ImDisk is free!)

The simplest solution would be to upgrade your system's RAM capacity to fit the drive capacity you want to host in memory and the programs you want to run at the same time.
You would have to buy DDR modules to install in that adapter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no SSD's that store their data on DRAM, those are only memory modules you put in DDRx slots. If you want an SSD that does wipe itself at reboot, you can look at the Gigabyte i-RAM, which adapts SATA to DDR1, or try software based solutions (I do not know how that works, but they exist)